# Change momentjs fromNow() output

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

So by default `moment(new Date()).add(2, 'days').fromNow()` will display `2 days` and as time goes by it will go to `1 day` and so on.
Is there a way to make it display in a custom format ? Like showing both hours in minutes. E.g: `1 day 23 hours 45 minutes`.
I've tried playing around with `moment.updateLocale`and change the`relativeTime` object but that just seems to change the string that is displayed after the duration ( E.g. : change `minutes` to `min` or `hours` to `h`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's no indication in [the documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/) that you can customize what the ranges *are*, just that you can customize what the ranges *say*. You seem to want to customize what the ranges are.

You may be able to do what you want using a [duration](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) rather than `fromNow`. The [`humanize` method](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/humanize/) accepts "[thresholds](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time-threshold/)."